# Common elements of two lists including repetitions

Tags: python, list, intersection

I've got two lists:

```
a = ['item.1','item.2','item.3', 'another_item'] 
b = ['item.4','item.5', 'another_item']
```

I'll split the elements to end up with

```
a = ['item', 'item', 'item', 'another_item']
b = ['item', 'item', 'another_item']
```

I would like take find the actual shared items, and end up with

```
c = ['item','item', 'another_item']
```

but `set(a).intersection(b)` will return me `['item', 'another_item']`

and

`c = [x for x in list1 if x in list2]` returns `['item', 'item', 'item', 'another_item']`

my lists actually consists of other items with multiple occurrences, so I can't just find out which list contains the least amount of occurrences for 'item' and iterate over it, if it contains more occurences of 'another_item'. What else can I try?

Comment: `set(a).intersection(b)` returns  `{'another_item'}` in my python. Neither list contains `'item'`.I do not understand what you mean by "compare them properly".

Comment: woops, yeah use a = [1,1,1,2] and b = [1,1,2] then. I'll edit my question, because the item.x might not be entirely relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) from [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) is able to handle multisets:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> a = ['item', 'item', 'item', 'another_item']
>>> b = ['item', 'item', 'another_item']

# create counter objects for a and b
>>> ca = Counter(a)
>>> cb = Counter(b)

>>> intersection = ca & cb
>>> intersection
Counter({'item': 2, 'another_item': 1})

>>> list(intersection.elements())
['item', 'item', 'another_item']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
a = ['item','item','item', 'another_item']
b = ['item','item', 'another_item']
b, common = b[:], [ e for e in a if e in b and (b.pop(b.index(e)) or True)]
print(common) # ['item', 'item', 'another_item']
```

This has the downside that a copy of one of the lists needs to be created, because the list comprehension will have to remove the iterated item. But it will work if you switch a and b.

Comment: This solution still allows accessing the attributes of e if it has any, nice